# which query is optimal id<>3 or id in {1,2,4}

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

if a table has many rows and each row has many columns which query is faster?

If the value of the column is within {1,2,3,4}

```
    SELECT * FROM table t WHERE t.column1<>3
```

Or

```
    SELECT * FROM table t WHERE t.column1 in {1,2,4}
```

Is it 3 compares vs 1 compare in these two cases?

Comment: is this for mysql, oracle or sql server? please tag only appropriate product

Comment: i want to know for each one

Comment: 'in' takes more time & also use of operators in query instead of words are faster..

Comment: @DevLakshman: `id IN(1,2,3)` is a replacement of `id=1 OR id=2 OR id=3`. @user4002899: in my opinion, for the limited number of values the second approach should be faster

Comment: yes..instead of 'in'  , 'OR' is faster

Comment: but vs first query is faster too?

Comment: Have a read [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3203/avoid-using-not-equal-in-where-clause/). The article confirms that the equality operator is faster than not equality. Therefore the second should be faster. @DevLakshman: Most likely the optimiser will convert the IN() operator to the set or OR operators

Comment: Why not check the explain plan for both the cases and check yourself?

Comment: May depend on if t.column1 is indexed?

Comment: Since you have the table and environments, can you show us the different execution plans, for MySQL, SQL Server and Oracle.

Comment: I have demonstrated the different scenarios in Oracle.

Comment: @cha I tested a few times.  t.column1<>3 is faster. So your statement is not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle, it would make a huge difference if you have an **INDEX**. You could make a small test case, and check the explain plan for each statement.

- **CASE# 1 : Without an Index**

**Setup**

For demo purpose, I am creating a small table from scott.emp table with 4 rows.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT * FROM emp WHERE empno IN (7369, 7499, 7521, 7566);

Table created.

SQL>
```

Since I am on 12c, CTAS doesn't need to gather statistics.

Let's see the explain plan:

**Using not equal to Condition**

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM t WHERE empno <> 7369;

Explained.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1601196873

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     3 |   117 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |     3 |   117 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("EMPNO"<>7369)

13 rows selected.

SQL>
```

**Using IN condition**

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM t WHERE empno IN (7499, 7521, 7566);

Explained.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1601196873

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     3 |   117 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |     3 |   117 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("EMPNO"=7499 OR "EMPNO"=7521 OR "EMPNO"=7566)

13 rows selected.

SQL>
```

- **CASE# 2 : With an Index**

**Setup**

```
SQL> CREATE INDEX t_indx ON t(empno);

Index created.

SQL>
```

**Using not equal to Condition**

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM t WHERE empno <> 7369;

Explained.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1601196873

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     3 |   117 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |     3 |   117 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("EMPNO"<>7369)

13 rows selected.

SQL>
```

**Using IN condition**

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM t WHERE empno IN (7499, 7521, 7566);

Explained.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 4217410154

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                            | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                     |        |     3 |   117 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  INLIST ITERATOR                     |        |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| T      |     3 |   117 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | T_INDX |     3 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access("EMPNO"=7499 OR "EMPNO"=7521 OR "EMPNO"=7566)

15 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: so what is your conclusion ? Which one is faster ?

Comment: With such small set of data, the optimizer has an optimal plan for almost all the cases. So, it would be completely depending on the cardinality and the selectivity of the index. OP can test it in his environment. Conclusion can't be firmly made based on my test case. And my test case is ONLY regarding Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

They are different. The first selects all records which don't have  an ID of 3 whereas the second selects all which are 1, 2 or 4. So for example the  record with ID = 5 is not included.

So performance should not be the reason to choose one query over the other.
Either you have millions of records in this table, then the `IN` approach doesn't work, or you have really only those 4 records, then, what are you asking?   Choose the most appropriate way in terms of readability and fail-safety and don't care about nano seconds.

Query optimization mostly relies on the RDBMS, so which are you using? In SQL-Server there should be no difference. But check it out yourself. 
[If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then race your horses.](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: if  value of  id in the table be in  {1,2,3,4}

Comment: @user4002899: even if there are only those 4 records in the table today, how do you know that this is always the case? Don't write quries that might fail in future.

Comment: @user4002899: query optimization mostly relies on the RDBMS, so which are you using? In SQL-Server there is no difference (imo).  But check it out yourself.

Comment: are you sure in sql server no diffrence and if it's oracle??

Comment: @user4002899: what are you trying to optimize? That doesn't make much sense at all. Since either you have millions of records in this table, then the `IN` approach doesn't work, or you have really only those 4 records, then what are you asking, if the database needs one nano second more with one approach? Choose the most appropriate way in terms of readability and fail-safety and don't care about nano seconds.

Comment: you're right my example was not good, i change it, there is a list of cityId and a cityid in each record, there is about 100000 record or more

Comment: If you have a "list of cityId", how do you want to replace it with `<>`? The question is still pretty vague.

Comment: column<>3 is find agents in city that is not some city and column in {1,2,4} is find agents in these cities

Answer (score 2):

Tested on sqlserver 2008 and 2012:

First method from question N <> 3:

```
CREATE TABLE #t (n INT)

;WITH N1 (N) AS 
(SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1),
(1)) n (N)),
N2 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2),
N3 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N2 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N2),
N4 (N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N1.N) FROM N3 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N3 AS N2),
N5 (N) AS (SELECT top 50000000 N%4 + 1 N FROM n4)
INSERT #t
SELECT n from n5

DECLARE @dummy int

DECLARE @a datetime = getdate()
SELECT @dummy = count(*)
FROM #t
WHERE N <> 3

SELECT datediff(ms, 0, getdate() - @a)
```

Result:

```
3886 milliseconds
```

Second method from question

```
CREATE TABLE #t (n INT)

;WITH N1 (N) AS 
(SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1),
(1)) n (N)),
N2 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2),
N3 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N2 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N2),
N4 (N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N1.N) FROM N3 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N3 AS N2),
N5 (N) AS (SELECT top 50000000 N%4 + 1 N FROM n4)
INSERT #t
SELECT n from n5

DECLARE @dummy int

DECLARE @a datetime = getdate()
SELECT @dummy = count(*) 
FROM #t
WHERE N in (1,2,4)

SELECT datediff(ms, 0, getdate() - @a)
```

Result:

```
4223 milliseconds
```

Conclusion

N <> 3 is faster(3886 vs 4223 milliseconds)

Yes it seems like a small difference, but if the column was declared as varchar(10) - CREATE TABLE #t (n INT) - the difference would be more significant(tested).